# Click on image in a photo gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

While I have programmed in many languages, I'm a JavaScript newbie.  Here is my situation.
A page is displayed.  On this page is a photo gallery.  A user clicks on one of these photos and a larger image is displayed.  I need to get either the Id or title of the specific photo that was clicked on.  I have done a LOT of Google searches and have tried a lot of different code snippets, but nothing has worked.  I suspect because I'm that knowledgeable in JavaScript, I am probably applying various potential solutions the wrong way.  I suspect the solution has to do with the onclick event.

PC

Comment: Please provide any attempts. Show some effort!

Comment: We can't help you if you don't display the relevant source code. So many difference ways/methods can be used to build a photo gallery and seeing how the one you're using works will help use answer your question. Without the source code we can't give you a correct answer, we can only play guessing games. Either upload your source code or expect more downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question with very little information and no source code to go from, I can only offer you this.

**Updated your question with the relevant source code for a better answer.**

```
onclick="YourFunction(this.id);"
```

Will fire a function called `YourFunction` and to get the ID you can:

```
function YourFunction(e){
// e= to the id of the element that fired the function
alert(e);
}
```

---

### **------ Demo Source Code ------**

```js
function GetId(e){
  alert('ID= '+e);
 }
```

```html
<p><b>Click the image to get the ID</b></p>
<img height="70px" id="Click_Me_Button_One" src="http://www.skybondsor.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/click-me.png" onclick="GetId(this.id);"/>

<img height="70px" id="Click_Me_Button_Two" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/vqKa5XeIG6W51gLV-wG_-DfX20FJxGxOw4-AoDQOJAzCqFeoED50-gabK94PFnWbHf8=w300" onclick="GetId(this.id);"/>

<img height="70px" id="Click_Me_Button_Three" src="http://www.dreems.org.in/click.jpg" onclick="GetId(this.id);"/>
```